# How to downsample a sequence x by an integer factor M with a single statement such as for loop or conditional statements

Tags: matlab, downsampling

I have already learning to use downsample() function inside Matlab. However, I am wondering if it can be implemented using basic for loop or if statement. Can anyone help me?
P.S Below is the code I have worked out, I would like to know if there is a different way to do it.

```
for i=1:M:length(x)
y=[y x(i)];
end
end
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `M` is a scalar integer value, and `x` is a vector, then `x(1:M:end)` takes every `M`th element.

```matlab
x = 1:14;
M = 4;
x(1:M:end)
```

```
ans =

     1     5     9    13
```

You can start at a different value too: `x(3:M:end)`.